# How to copy only the most recent image in a folder?

Tags: image, directory, copy, duplicates, webcam

I have a DSLR camera taking photos of a construction project.  The camera is hooked USB to a computer that fires an image every 15 minutes.  This file is saved to a network location. (Folder A)  In the end, I'll be doing a time lapse with these images.

I'd also like to be able to display these images on a website.  So what I envision is a folder on my web server that only has ONE file in it....  The most recent image taken from my DSLR. (Folder B)

So the script would need to -
1) Delete the existing file in Folder B
2) Copy the most recent file from Folder A to Folder B (and ONLY the most recent file)
3) Rename that image file to the same name as was there (so I can embed that singular filename in my web page)...  So something like "webimage.jpg"  This way the file in that folder is always named "webimage.jpg"

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how you implemented the image capture function. It's better to use a third-party SDK, such as Dynamic Webcam SDK: capture images, upload them to your system and copy an image from one location to anther. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/webcam-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this

```
$ ls -lat $d0

total 88
drwx------+ 1 dmi Aucun     0 Jul  3 13:51 .
drwx------+ 1 dmi Aucun     0 Jul  3 13:51 bb
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 dmi Aucun     0 Jul  3 13:34 ..
drwx------+ 1 dmi Aucun     0 Jul  3 13:34 aa
-rwx------  1 dmi Aucun 33203 Jun 30 12:30 arp.o
-rwx------  1 dmi Aucun 20235 Jul  2  2007 makefile.in
-rwx------  1 dmi Aucun 24264 Jun 25  2007 isakmp.c
-rwx------  1 dmi Aucun  4586 Nov 21  2006 ftpctrl.c
```

Clearly, the most recent file

```
$d0/arp.o
```

given by

```
ls -lAt  $d0  |perl -ne  'next if/^d/; if( s/.* \d\d:\d\d //){ print ;exit}'
```

is then copied into $d1/mypic.png with this liner

```
cp $d0/$( ls -lAt $d0  |perl -ne 'next if/^d/; if( s/.* \d\d:\d\d //){ print ;exit}')  $d1/mypic.bmp
```

.

;-)